# How to add a shared base setter

Tags: java

having thoses classes:

```
public abstract class A{
   //i need a shared setter here to do some common code. 
}
public class B extends A{
   private Long id;
   public void setId(Long id){
       this.id = id;
   }
}
public class C extends A{
   private String id;
   public void setId(String id){
       this.id = id;
   }
}
```

What is the best way to do that, i dont know if it has a relation-ship with "dynamic proxies" ?

Comment: I think your second `class B` should read `class C`?

Comment: yes it is, i already fix it thanks

Comment: Do you want setId() for both class C and B to do some common task in A? Is this task dependent on `id` value?

Comment: yes and yes, if the id is a composite id i need to set some setting on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to use generics, for example...

```
public abstract class A<T>{
    private T id;
    public void setId(T id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
public class B extends A<Long>{
}
public class C extends A<String>{
}
```

For more details, have a look at [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: Very good idea, but this mean the modification of 400 entities, may be  there is another way

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK If you already have them defined, then no, not really.  Best choice would be to write a tool to update the existing code, assuming you have the source...

Comment: This was a design choice, yes I know, I do this all the time do, this is something you will learn to see with experience.  Based on the information you've provided, generics is the best option, whether you're starting out or retrofitting the code...

Comment: but if the id property is defined in the A class how to put specific annotation like Id or EmbededId ?

Comment: I guess it would depend, what framework are you using that could support it?

Comment: its JPA, with hibernate implementation

Comment: oubs i think that i could override the getter and put the annotation

Comment: I'm not sure the annotation is going to do a lot beyond providing a lookup for these frameworks to bind against.  Because the data type is essentially undefined, you either need to set the `id` as an `Object` or use generics

Comment: using generics, doest it mean that the getter and the setter is no more available for the field?

Comment: i mean the the reflexion getter and setter

Comment: Based on my little bit of testing, they seem to be coming back as `Object`

Comment: first test give this error :Record.id has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type

Comment: hibernate should probably provide a way to handle generic, i should find the solution

Comment: combinig your solution with this should do the job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009344/hibernate-and-generic-field-mapping

Comment: That seems like a viable solution